# JPA embed constant value

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have the following tables:

`item (item_id, creator, title)`

`offer (item_id, seller, price_in_usd_cents)`

`exchange_rate (usd_cents_per_euro_cents)`

One item can have multiple offers.

Exchange rate table has single row with single column and updates daily.

The problem: show item with price from creator both in USD and EUR.

My mappings so far:

```
@Entity
class Item(
    @Id
    @Column(name = "item_id")
    var itemId: String = "",

    @Column
    var creator: String = "",

    @Column
    var title: String = "",

    @ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns(
        JoinColumn(name = "item_id", referencedColumnName = "item_id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        JoinColumn(name = "creator", referencedColumnName = "seller", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    )
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    var offerFromCreator: Offer? = null,
)
```

```
@Entity
class Offer(
    @EmbeddedId
    var id: OfferId = OfferId(),

    @Column(name = "price")
    var priceInUsdCents: BigInteger = BigInteger.ZERO
)
```

```
@Embeddable
class OfferId(
    @Column
    var seller: String = "",

    @Column(name = "item_id")
    var itemId: String = ""
) : Serializable
```

```
@Entity
class ExchangeRate(
    @Id
    @Column(name = "usd_cents_per_euro_cents")
    var usdCentsPerEuroCents: BigInteger = BigInteger.ONE
)
```

Of course, I can write raw SQL or make several queries using EntityManager, but I'd like to have right mapping with single query.

The idea is to embed `ExchangeRate` into `Offer` and have the calculated field `priceInEurCents`, but I have now idea how to do it and if it's even possible with JPA (I'm using Hibernate).

Comment: You say that: *One item can have multiple offers* , but I do not see it from your mapping.

Comment: @SternK you are right, I didn't put OneToMany for item -> offer. But it's not necessary for my use case. I need to retrieve only one offer from item's creator. That's why I put ManyToOne (actually it's OneToOne).

Comment: You should probably do this by performing a JPQL query. Depending on what you want to do with the result, you can query it into a DTO.

https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you probably need to change your mappings since you wrote that an item can have multiple offers to something similar to the following:

```
@Entity
class Item(
    @Id
    @Column(name = "item_id")
    var itemId: String = "",

    @Column
    var creator: String = "",

    @Column
    var title: String = "",

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "item")
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    var offers: mutableList<Offer>,
)

@Entity
class Offer(
    @EmbeddedId
    var id: OfferId = OfferId(),

@ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns(
        JoinColumn(name = "item_id", referencedColumnName = "item_id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        JoinColumn(name = "seller", referencedColumnName = "creator", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    )
    var item: Item,

    @Column(name = "price")
    var priceInUsdCents: BigInteger = BigInteger.ZERO
)
```

You could calculate this on-demand by providing a `ExchangeRate` object. You can also write a query for this and put that stuff into a DTO and I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(Item.class)
public interface ItemDto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getName();
    @Mapping("ExchangeRate[usdCentsPerEuroCents IS NOT NULL].usdCentsPerEuroCents")
    BigInteger getExchangeRate();
    Set<OfferDto> getOffers();
    default OfferDto getOfferToUse() { ... }
    default BigInteger getPriceInUsdCents() {
        return getOfferToUse().getPriceInUsdCents();
    }
    default BigInteger getPriceInEuroCents() {
        return getPriceInUsdCents().divide(getExchangeRate());
    }

    @EntityView(Offer.class)
    interface OfferDto {
        @IdMapping("id.seller")
        String getSeller();
        BigInteger getPriceInUsdCents();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`ItemDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, ItemDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<ItemDto> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!